# Lamar with MediatR registering constructor dependencies, is there a better way?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mediatr, lamar

I am using Lamar and i have added a load of dependencies which work in my controllers.

When i try to use a handler from MediarR i am having to explicitly set the Ctor dependancies like so:

```
serviceRegistry
            .ForConcreteType<UpdateStockItemPricingHandler>().Configure
            .Scoped()
            .Ctor<ClientAppContext>("dbContext").Is<ClientAppContext>();
```

I am going to have to do this for every single handler? seems very tedious, the `ClientAppContext` dependencie is already registered in the container so why does the handler not auto inject it? without needing the above code.

Do i need to somehow make Handlers aware of all the dependencies that are in my container?

Here is an example of some dependencies i have registered:

```
serviceRegistry.Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.AssemblyContainingType<Ping>();
            scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));
            scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));
            scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestExceptionAction<>));
            scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>));
        });
        
        serviceRegistry.For<MediatR.IMediator>().Use<Mediator>().Transient();
        serviceRegistry.For<ServiceFactory>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance);

        serviceRegistry
            .ForConcreteType<ServiceHealthCheckHandler>().Configure
        .Scoped()
            .Ctor<IService>("environmentService").Is<EnvironmentService>()
            .Transient();
        
        serviceRegistry
            .ForConcreteType<GetStockItemPricingHandler>().Configure
            .Scoped()
            .Ctor<ClientAppContext>("dbContext").Is<ClientAppContext>();
        
        serviceRegistry
            .ForConcreteType<UpdateStockItemPricingHandler>().Configure
            .Scoped()
            .Ctor<ClientAppContext>("dbContext").Is<ClientAppContext>();



        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile()));
        IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Comment: What version of Lamar are you using?

Comment: @mxmissile 2.0.0